# Is there a way to embed the src of @font-face?

Tags: css, font-face

I don't want references to other files in my CSS.

I'm trying to find a way to embed the font file inside my CSS (TTF, EOT, WOFF).
I know that there is a way to embed an image, for example:

```
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64, +IDx4OnhtcG1ldG…+kJggg==");
```

Is there a way to do the same with the src value of a `@font-face`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base64 for this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'latoregular';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAHwwABMAAAAA4IwAAQAAAAAAAAAAA[...]) format('woff'),
    url('lato-reg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can generate base64 font in http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't base64 EOT files for IE8 and below. Caniuse reports "support in Internet Explorer 8 is limited to images and linked resources like CSS files, not HTML files."

Comment: @user1511864, no problemo. If it worked for you mark my answer as correct ;).